# Rendimiento de consulta con servidor vinculado

Tags: sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy trabajando con un **servidor vinculado Oracle** en **SQL Server**.

Quiero crear una vista de mi tabla en **SQL** y tengo todos los datos que necesito mostrar en el `Select`, pero el tipo de categoria, campo `COMP_NEW`, esta en el servidor vinculado **Oracle**.

La consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT distinct ls.compNew,
      ls.idPlant,
      ls.plant,
          ls.compAct,
      --es.Categoria,
      ls.Proyecto,
      ls.status,
      ls.FechaIni,
      ls.FechaFinal
  FROM [myLocalServer].[dbo].[AjustesTbl] ls
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([myLinkServer],'SELECT DISTINCT , Comp, Categoria  from tblComp')) exs
ON 
exs.comp = ls.compNew
```

[image: PlanDeEjecucion]

Esa consulta tal cual arroja 18.986 registros(muchos duplicados), y tarda 2 sec en ejecutarse.

Como pueden observar tengo comentada la columna `categoria` (necesito esa columna). Si quito el comentario de la misma la consulta tarda alrededor de *3 minutos*. La tabla del servidor vinculado tiene alrededor de 60.000 registros.

¿Cómo puedo optimizar mi consulta con todos los registros que necesito para que no tarde tanto tiempo en ejecutarse?

Comment: ¿Cuantas filas tienes en la tabla de Oracle? Si son pocas puede ser mejor que insertes todas en una tabla temporal y esa la uses en la consulta.

Comment: ¿Porque hacer un `SELECT * from tblComp`, al servidor vinculado cuando solo quieres usar `comp y Categoria`? Primero mira a ver cuanto te tarda en traer del servidor vinculado las mínimas columnas que necesites.

Comment: @LuisCazares La tabla de Oracle tiene 60.000 registros

Comment: @Javifer2 modifique la consulta al servidor vinculado requiriendo solo lo que necesito y bajo a 30 segundos, aun se podira optimizar la query? He modificado la query en la pregunta con la modificacion del query.

Comment: Es considerable de 3min a 30seg, sin embargo incluso así 60mil registros son 'pocos' registros, tienes que confirmar que la lentitud venga del servidor linkeado, en cualquier caso tienes índices creados?

Comment: @Isanchezo, la consulta solo con los datos al servidor vinculado (las dos columnas) tarda 0.154 segundos

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta el *Plan de Ejecución* de tu consulta.

Comment: @Sal He agregado el plan de ejecucion a la pregunta, mencionar que a esta hora de la noche no hay nadie conultando la db, y tardo 9 segundos, bastante bueno pero repito no hay nadie haciendo consultas.

Comment: Amerita ver el plan de ejecución en XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que la tabla externa tiene relativamente pocos registros, se pueden pasar a la instancia local y obtener un mejor rendimiento.

```
CREATE TABLE #ExternaltblComp(
 comp int,
 Categoria varchar(255)
)
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_ExternaltblComp ON #ExternaltblComp( comp)

INSERT INTO #ExternaltblComp
SELECT Comp, 
       Categoria
FROM OPENQUERY([myLinkServer],'SELECT DISTINCT Comp, Categoria  from tblComp') 

SELECT DISTINCT 
      ls.compNew,
      ls.idPlant,
      ls.plant,
      ls.compAct,
      es.Categoria,
      ls.Proyecto,
      ls.status,
      ls.FechaIni,
      ls.FechaFinal
FROM  [myLocalServer].[dbo].[AjustesTbl] ls
LEFT JOIN #ExternaltblComp exs ON exs.comp = ls.compNew;
```

Por favor, revisa la estructura de la tabla y revisa que está causando duplicados para ver si es posible eliminar los DISTINCT que son operaciones costosas.

Comment: me sirvio tu aportacion, se puede cerrar esta pregunta.
Gracias